# Property of Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform, mathematical-physics, perturbation-theory

I've been reading a physics book about non-perturbative contributions to the path integral, and there is an equality I'm having difficulties to understand; I thought it might relate to an identity I do not know of Laplace transform.

> $ S_{l}(\beta,g)=\sum_{n} \frac{\lambda^n}{2 \pi i n} \beta e^{-\beta}\int ds e^{-s\beta}[I_{l}(s)]^n$             **(71)**
>
> It is easy to verify that
> $I_{l}(s)=I_{-l}(s)$. From equation (71) one now derives the result
>
> $ S_{l}(\beta,g)=\sum_{N} e^{-\beta E_{NL}} $
>
> with $E_{NL}=S_{N,l}+1$, in which $S_{NL}$ is the solution of the equation
>
> $I_{l}(s)=\frac{1}{\lambda}$

Any suggestion is appreciated, and I hope my question is well placed. I did not include the expression for $I_{l}(s)$ because it does not seem fundamental to understand which relation he used, but I can obviously add it later if required.

**EDIT:**
ok, I think I got it: he exchanges order of summation and integration, obatining the geometric serie, which has poles where that equation is satisfied. Is it right?